# How to show firebase storage file upload progress

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

I am trying to show the progress of the file I am uploading to firebase storage in a progress indicator how can I achieve this.?

Note that I am a uploading two files at the same time.

here is my code.

```
Future<String?> _uploadFileToStorage(BuildContext context,File file, path) async {
    try {
      var task = _firebaseStorage.ref().child(path);
      var status = await task.putFile(file);
    print(status.state);
      return task.getDownloadURL();
    } catch (err) {
      print(err.toString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: check this out : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20803

Answer (score 2):

first take variable `bool load` and make initialy `load=false` when your function start make `load=true`and at then end of your function load=false, so  on your parent widget `load==true?CircularProgressIndicator():Scaffold(),`
so here you function

```
Future<String?> _uploadFileToStorage(BuildContext context,File file, path) async {

        try {
       setState({
          load=true;
            });
          var task = _firebaseStorage.ref().child(path);
          var status = await task.putFile(file);
        print(status.state);
          return task.getDownloadURL();
        setState({
            load=false;
              })
        } catch (err) {
          print(err.toString());
      setState({
            load=false;
              })
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can track the uploading progress by simply using the following code:

```
status.snapshotEvents.listen((TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
        print('Task state: ${snapshot.state}');
        print('Progress: ${(snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100} %');

        switch (snapshot.state) {
          case TaskState.paused:
            // TODO: Handle this case.
            break;
          case TaskState.running:
            return CircularProgressIndicator(
                value: (snapshot.bytesTransferred > 0 && snapshot.totalBytes > 0) ? snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes : null);

            break;
          case TaskState.success:
            // TODO: Handle this case.
            break;
          case TaskState.canceled:
            // TODO: Handle this case.
            break;
          case TaskState.error:
            // TODO: Handle this case.
            break;
        }
      }, onError: (e) {
        // The final snapshot is also available on the status via `.snapshot`,
        // this can include 2 additional states, `TaskState.error` & `TaskState.canceled`
        print(status.snapshot);
      });
```

Comment: getting this error  ` The getter 'snapshotEvents' isn't defined for the type 'TaskSnapshot'. `

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
// gets the upload task for the current image
UploadTask? task = await uploadFileToFirebase("images", File(image.path));

// updates the upload progress
task.snapshotEvents.listen((event) {
   upload_progress = event.bytesTransferred.toDouble() / event.totalBytes.toDouble() * 100;

   print("upload progress is $upload_progress");

   notifyListeners();
 }).onError((error) {
   print("there was an error boss $error");
 });

 // uploads the file (image or video) to firebase
 final snapshot = await task.whenComplete(() => {});

 // gets the file's (image or video) url
 String media_url = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
```